# Will SFDC manufacture batches from concurrent operations?

Tags: apex, trigger, dml, bulkification, bulk

So, like all SFDC developers worth his/her salt, I know when writing triggers and other code, we need to bulkify.  And I have a pretty good handle on how to do that, so I am not asking about that.

But rather, let's say, hypothetically speaking, you know your client will never load data using the Apex Data Loader or any sort of equivalent.

And let's  say, still hypothetically speaking, you know that your target SObject does not now and will never exist in any sort of relationship to another SObject, so the only way it will ever be created or modified is when a human manually submits a form through the web-ui.

It seems to me, in such an instance, there would never be any bulk operation, unless your client had concurrent users and SFDC was smart enough to say "hey, all these people have insert Hypothetical__c operations queued.  Let's combine all of these into one bulkified insert operation."

Does anyone know if that is how SFDC works?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce won't combine operations from different transactions, especially from different users. The only time you'll see bulk operations is when multiple records are created/updated/deleted together by an app.

Answer (score 3):

As each of these hypothetical users is working in their own hypothetical execution contexts, I think you can assume that SFDC wouldn't combine these changes into a single batch. Which would be problematic anyway as these hypothetical users could have different permissions.

But I have to admit: all of this is highly hypothetical...